# How to visualise java n-ary tree

Tags: java, visualization, n-ary-tree

I would like to know if there is a way to visualise non binary tree in this way : the root to be at the top, its children under and so on .. It is important the children to be connected (with lines may be) to their parents. The visualisation may be in the console or even better-in graphical way with some other libraries or sth.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Pleas edit your question and show us your code...

Comment: I succeeded visualising it this way: root in the left and children in the right ,but this didn't help me ..I read about JUNG and JGraph but couldnt find any examples how to use them :/

Comment: You could try to recreate something like this [git log](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9074343/3280538)

Comment: this is not what i am looking for :/ ,the result should look like https://www.google.bg/search?q=n-ary+tree&biw=1024&bih=530&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjN_L6gq_3LAhWDAJoKHXz0C6UQ_AUIBigB#imgrc=HJNbDyjP6KmG-M%3A  or something like that.